# d3 bar chart grow from height 0 to bars at loading

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to animate a d3 bar chart, such that when loaded, all the bars will 'grow' taller elegantly from x-axis from height 0 to its scaled height. Instead my bar chart just 'slam down' from top left to the svg.   [See my observableHq demo.](https://observablehq.com/@kuankuan27/bar-chart)

My bars are drawn in the following way:

```
  svg
.selectAll("rect")
.attr("height", 0)
.attr("y", (d) => y(0))
.data(data)
.join("rect")
.transition()
.duration(500)
.attr("x", (d, i) => x(i))
.attr("y", (d) => y(d.value))
.attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d.value))
.attr("width", x.bandwidth())
.delay((d, i) => i * 10);
```

I was hoping the 2nd and 3rd line serve as the starting point of the bar, then the transition() will allow it to transit to the attributes after the .duration(500) line. But it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
svg
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .join("rect")
  .attr("height", 0)
  .attr("y", (d) => y(0))
  .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i))
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("y", (d) => y(d.value))
  .attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d.value));
```